# Android how to align text right and left editText

Tags: android, android-layout, localization, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` having hint and text in it. Also app using Arabic localization also. For Arabic I've used `android:gravity="right"`. It's working fine but my edit text allows only numeric input. It is expected to show numbers inputted left aligned, and the Arabic hint towards the right aligned. My `EditText` xml like follows

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sampleEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="النص عينة"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="#F3F3F3"
    android:inputType="number"
/>
```

Please help me.. Thanks for any help or tutorial in advance..

Comment: try android:gravity="start"

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634948/android-edittext-align-text-to-right-and-label-to-left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the `<application>` element in your `manifest` file.

`minSdkVersion` should be **17 or higher**

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare in your app manifest that your app supports RTL mirroring.
   Specifically, add android:supportsRtl="true" to the `<application>` element in your manifest file.
2. Change all of your app's "left/right" layout properties to new "start/end" equivalents.
   If you are targeting your app to Android 4.2 (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 17 or higher), then you should use “start” and “end” instead of “left” and “right”. For example, android:paddingLeft should become android:paddingStart.
   If you want your app to work with versions earlier than Android 4.2 (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 16 or less), then you should add “start” and end” in addition to “left” and “right”. For example, you’d use both android:paddingLeft and android:paddingStart.

For Details see [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)